# unable to access nested objects with angular ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**"Private" property access no longer allowed:**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/7l4j70wlPwI/dgt4chDVseAJ

My $scope returns an array. An object within this array that looks like this:

```
0: Object
$$hashKey: "004"
FIRST_NAME: "DAVID"
LAST_NAME: "SHORT"
_id: Object
$oid: "5286f54e5b5f47d3bd3145bd"
```

I would like to have access to both FIRST_NAME and $oid. I can get first name like this:

```
  <li ng-repeat="result in apiResult">
    <form ng-submit="findone()">
      <span type="text" ng-model="searchTerm"  class="">{{result._id}}</span>
      <span class="">{{result.FIRST_NAME}}</span>
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
  </li>
```

I can not access _id. How can I return the id in this example?

Comment: nope. this does not work

Comment: Damn NoSQL...my `_id` typically comes back in just a key/val pair, this seems to have kept the embedded object..

Comment: In your example it looks like you are just trying to display result._id, but it is an Object type. Is there a primitive field within the object you would like to display?

Comment: Also, why are you adding empty class attributes?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the introduction of `private` properties in Angular version 1.2.

#### Underscore-prefixed/suffixed properties are non-bindable

*This change introduces the notion of "private" properties (properties whose names begin and/or end with an underscore) on the scope chain. These properties will not be available to Angular expressions (i.e. interpolation in templates and strings passed to $parse)*

[Read more..](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#underscore-prefixed/suffixed-prorperties-are-non-bindable)